# IntelliJ IDEA Making 2 modules build in 2 module project

Tags: build, module, intellij-idea

I have a project with 2 modules (from the IPR file):

```
  <component name="ProjectModuleManager">
    <modules>
      <module fileurl="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/20.0.iml" filepath="$PROJECT_DIR$/20.0.iml" />
      <module fileurl="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/20.1.iml" filepath="$PROJECT_DIR$/20.1.iml" />
    </modules>
  </component>
```

The problem is that only the first module in this modules list is "active" and has its sources folder recognized as such. The second one is not built and the sources folder is displayed like a regular folder.

When I change the order of modules in the above XML the first one in the list becomes "active" instead.

How do I set it up so that both modules are built?

I'm using IDEA 9.

Comment: How does it look in the IDE under Project Structure?  You should be able to select your source folder and then identify it as a source (using the blue colored Sources button).

Comment: It *is* marked as a source folder in the project structure settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to right-click the inactive sources folder and choose `Mark directory as` -> `Source root` ? Alternatively you can use Project Structure dialog and setup your source directories there.

EDIT:
It seems Idea also expects modules and their iml files to be in separate subfolders.

Comment: Both modules have their source directories specified if I look in the settings or directly in the XML.

Comment: Source folders are specified in iml files of the modules as `<sourceFolder>` tags - did you check there?

Comment: Yes, both IMLs have the source folders specified.

Comment: The only difference I can see from what you posted is that in my case modules and their iml files are in dedicated subdirectories, also they have more distinctive names. Maybe the fact both start with "20" followed by dot is somehow confusing Idea?

Comment: Indeed! Putting the IML files in their respective subdirectories helped! You could add this to the answer now. Thank a lot!